# how to extract a zip file and then grab its path and set the path to system path

Tags: batch-file, system-paths

so if you dont get it what my actual problem is, it is that

```
@echo off

:: Step 1: Extract Zip File
powershell -Command "Expand-Archive -Path '%CD%\cyrex.zip' -DestinationPath '%CD%\cyrex'"

:: Step 2: Add Cyrex Folder to System Path
set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\cyrex

:: Step 3: Compile and Run Cyrex Program
cyrex program1.crx

:: Step 4: Clean Up (optional)
del cyrex.zip
```

this i asked chatgpt to tell me a method to extract zip folder so that i can extract and add the path to system path, but the problem is that it isn't adding the path to the system path

i tried everything but none of them was working please help guys ;-;

Comment: BTW, it would be safer to use `Set "PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\cyrex"`. It might seem like a subtle difference, but imagine what could happen if a location in the value string contained an ampersand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are currently only setting the path for your current window.

To set it permanently you need to use

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\cyrex
```

Comment: it worked when i used set instead of setx thanks

Comment: No, this is not the correct way to do this. You have now corrupted your User PATH variable by adding everything from your System PATH to it. Go on, open a Command prompt window, type `PATH`, and press the `[ENTER`] key to take a look. Why @BadriVishalManiTripathi, have you marked this as accepted, given my opening statement, and the fact you have not used this, and your code already had the `set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\cyrex` line.

Comment: Wan't that what he wanted to do? He wanted it to be added to the system path and not just to the current open command prompt.